# Serial keys with ECC

Tags: security, cryptography, code-access-security, elliptic-curve

I want to (or created) serial keys based on elliptic key cryptography. What I want to do is to encode information in the serial which can be publicly verified but only created by me. The initial idea is from http://www.ssware.com/cryptolicensing/cryptolicensing_net.htm where they can create serials where information is encrypted. However, this is based on RSA resulting in large numbers. Therefore I want to build something similar on my own.

I then found: http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/algorithms/general/article.php/c12799/Product-Keys-Based-on-Elliptic-Curve-Cryptography.htm

However, I see no benifit in this: They choose domain parameters which needs to be known by the app and the creator. The public key is used to encrypt (generate the serial) whereas the private key is in the application and used to decrypt. However, knowing the domain parameters and the private key, it is easy to derive the public key for ECIES, right?

The next idea would be to just encode the information arbitrarily and append a signature based on ECDSA to it. But this results in a large serial number.

What I am really looking for is a solution similar to http://ellipter.com where they use the right concept: The private key to generate the serial and the public key to verify them. And the keys they show in the screenshot are very short: For 128 Bit keys only around 30 characters.

What is the correct way to do this? Do I miss the correct scheme for this? It can't be ECDSA, it can't be ECIES. But what else?

Answer (score 5):

What you need is an elliptic curve [digital signature scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature), such as [ECDSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_DSA).

Basically, your key generation server will hold the private half of the keypair, while the software you distribute will contain the public half.  Your serial key will consist of a simple serial number, plus a signature of that number using the private key.  When the number is entered by the user, the software checks that the signature is valid using its public key.

You can also use the same scheme for product activation keys; in this case, the data you'd be signing wouldn't be just a serial number, but some kind of digest string identifying the user and possibly some features of the system they're installing the software on.

Now, the bad news is that, unfortunately, an ECDSA signature with a non-trivial security level is still pretty long for a license key.  You can reduce the signature length by reducing the security level, but then it becomes possible to forge the signatures by brute force.  Basically, you're going to have a tradeoff between security and usability.  You could also try other signature schemes with short signatures, like [Schnorr signatures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schnorr_signature) or possibly something like the [McEliece-based signature scheme described in this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.109.3745), but even these might be a tight fit for a user-typeable license key.

---

What generally confuses people who first encounter digital signatures in the form of RSA signatures is that the [RSA cryptosystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29) is kind of unusual, in that the same basic algorithm can be used for *both* [public-key encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) and for digital signatures, and, at a low level, the two operations are kind of dual, such that the RSA signature operation can be viewed as "encrypting with the private key" and the signature verification as "decrypting with the public key" (which is the opposite of what you'd do for normal public-key encryption).

However, for most other public key cryptosystems, no such duality holds: generically, digital signature schemes are completely different from public key encryption schemes (although they're often based on similar mathematical problems).  Indeed, even for RSA, the signature and encryption operations become dissimilar once you start considering details like [padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_1), which are essential if you want to turn the basic "textbook RSA" algorithm into something that can actually be used as a secure and practical cryptosystem.

Comment: Hmm, I elaborated that I already implemented a scheme. I am aware of signature schemes, ECC, RSA. What my question is how Ellipter is able to create so **short** serial numbers. Furthermore, it can't be a plain signature because data is encrypted additionally.

Comment: I noticed that after answering, and added a bit about it above. They _may_ be using some other signature scheme besides ECDSA, but they could also just be skimping on the security level. Without knowing what algorithm they're actually using, it's hard to say what they really mean by "128-bit key strength".